# Closed formula for distances relating to Collatz conjecture?

Tags: collatz-conjecture

I've been messing with the collatz conjecture for a while now, and I've found that another way to prove it is through proving that for any number $n$ there is at least one $k$ ($n$ is any odd input and $k$ is the total stopping time of $n$) where the output of the function $$2^{\lceil log_2{(n3^k)} \rceil}-n3^k$$can be written in the form of $$3^{k-1}(2^{a_1}) + 3^{k-2}(2^{a_2}) + ... + 3^{k-k}(2^{a_{k}})$$ where there are $k$ terms and $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 $ and so on. Additionally, $a_1$ must be zero. For example, when $k = 2$, the numbers which can be written in this form are 5, 7, 11, 19, 35,... which are $3^{2-1}(2^0) + 3^{2-2}(2^{1,2,3,4,5})$. A number with total stopping time 2 should be one of these numbers away from the nearest larger power of 2 when multiplied by $3^2$. ex: $2^{\lceil log_2{((3)3^2)}\rceil}-(3)3^2 = 5$, which is included on the list for $k = 2$. I'd like to know if there is a closed formula for numbers that can be written this way. I doubt it, because each value of $k$ adds another variable which can be tweaked, but my knowledge is severely limited.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean by $\lceil n 3^k\rceil $but it looks like formula (1) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4649071/considerations-on-the-sequences-of-the-3n-1-problem)

Comment: @user140242 I apologize, I meant to write $\lceil log_2{(n3^k)} \rceil$, but I accidentally forgot the logarithm. I fixed this mistake in the post.

Comment: I as a lay person am thinking that probability or two consequitive odds is zero whereas probability of two consequitive evens is NOT zero and since even means halving of the value, the sequence eventually will reduce to 1. Would I be correct in following that line of reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

For odd integer $n_i$, $n_{i+1} = \dfrac{3n_{i} + 1}{2^{a_1}}$. Define ${A_i = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i}a_j}$ for $i \gt 0$ and $A_0=0$, then
$$n_{k+1} = \dfrac{3^kn_1 + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}3^{k-1-i}2^{A_i}}{2^{A_k}}$$
If $n_{k+1} = 1$ then
$$n_1 = \dfrac{2^{A_k} - \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}3^{k-1-i}2^{A_i}}{3^k}$$
This is your equation except that the exponent for $2$ should be $A_k$ which is the total number of divide by $2$'s to get to 1.
So $n_1$ reaches $1$ if for some $k$ if there are integer $a_i \gt 0$ and hence $A_i$ that satisfy this equation. Note that if there is a solution for a given $k$ and $a_i$, then there is also a solution for $k+1$ by appending $a_{k+1} = 2$. This corresponds to looping once the sequence reaches $1$. So there is always a trivial solution for any $k$ which is $n_i = 1$ with $a_i = 2$ which corresponds to the sequence $1,1,1,1,...$ with $a_i = 2$ and the sum = $2^{2k} - 3^k$ and $A_k = 2k$. Similarly, $a_i = 4,2,2$ is a solution for $k = 3$ corresponding to the sequence $5,1,1$ These probably aren't the solutions you're interested in though. There apparently isn't a known closed form solution to finding the $k$ and $a_i$ given an $n_1$ otherwise the Collatz conjecture would have been proven since this equation (that you rediscovered) is known (a bit of a flip answer I know).

Answer (score 0):

For odd integer $\quad n \quad$ fixed $ \quad n_0=n \quad$ and for $\quad i>0 \quad$ fixed

$n_i=\frac{3 \cdot n_{i-1} +1}{2^{a_i}} \quad$ with $\quad n_i \quad$ odd integer

then

$n_1=\frac{3 \cdot n_0 +1}{2^{a_1}}=\frac{3 \cdot n +1}{2^{a_1}}$

$n_2=\frac{3 \cdot n_1 +1}{2^{a_2}}=\frac{3 \cdot \frac{3 \cdot n +1}{2^{a_1}} +1}{2^{a_2}}$

$\cdots$

$n_k=\frac{3^k\cdot n +3^{k-1} +\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-2}{3^{i}\cdot2^{\sum_{j=1}^{k-1-i} {a_j}}} }{2^{\sum_{j=1}^{k}{a_j}}}$

then define  $ \quad k_{e}=\sum_{j=1}^{k}{a_j} \quad$ number of times the sequence has been divided by $\quad 2 \quad$

if $ \quad n_k=1$ we have

$$3^k\cdot n=2^{k_{e}} -3^{k-1}-\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-2}{3^{i}\cdot2^{\sum_{j=1}^{k-1-i} {a_j}}} $$

then

$$3^k\cdot n<2^{k_{e}}$$

from which

$$k_{e}>\log_2{(n\cdot 3^k)}$$

or

$$\quad k_{e} \geq \left\lceil \log_2{(n\cdot 3^k)} \right\rceil$$

It's probably also possible to come up with an upper bound for $\quad k_{e}$.